# How to add values to dropdown list based on the value of another inputbox in symfony 1.4

Tags: drop-down-menu, symfony-1.4, dynamic-values

i am working on symfony 1.4 in Orangehrm. I am unable to add values in dropdown list based on the value entered by the user during execution. What are the ways to solve them ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: no worries found out. Thanks by the way

Comment: Good to hear that.